# Memory release problems in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain

I have a real-life example that I have in my project below. My aim is to pick out the most likely phone number for SMS receptions, and only that (phone)number. All works well when I don't release memory at the end, but we can't have that, can we. My question is: Where (and how) is the correct way to release memory in the example below?

```
// Called after a person has been selected by the user. Return YES if you want the person to be displayed.
// Return NO to do nothing (the delegate is responsible for dismissing the peoplepicker)
- (BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *) peoplePicker 
    shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: (ABRecordRef)person
{     
 // Retrieving the person's most likely phonenumber (kABPersonPhoneProperty)
 CFStringRef phoneNumber, phoneNumberLabel;

 ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValueReference = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType); 
 multiValueReference = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

 NSMutableString *mostLikelyPhoneNumber = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

 // Iterating through all the phone numbers in the list
 for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValueReference); i++) {

  phoneNumberLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValueReference, i);
  phoneNumber      = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValueReference, i);

  // Converting to NSString for easier comparison (this way I have only NSStrings)
  NSString *NSStringphoneNumberLabel =  [[NSString alloc] init];
  NSString *NSStringphoneNumber =  [[NSString alloc] init];

  // Copying the contents of the CFStringRef to my NSString pointers
  NSStringphoneNumberLabel = (NSString *) phoneNumberLabel;
  NSStringphoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneNumber;

  LOG (@"Phone number: %@/%@", phoneNumberLabel, phoneNumber); // No problem so far!
  LOG (@"Phone number: %@/%@", NSStringphoneNumberLabel, NSStringphoneNumber); // No problem so far!

  // If this phone number has a "iphone" or a "mobile" label, save it to mostLikelyPhoneNumber
  if ([NSStringphoneNumberLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"]) 
  {
   mostLikelyPhoneNumber = (NSMutableString *) NSStringphoneNumber;
  }

  else if ([NSStringphoneNumberLabel isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
  {
   mostLikelyPhoneNumber = (NSMutableString *) NSStringphoneNumber;
   // However, if it was an "iphone", break out of the loop. (Can't get any better than iPhone)
   break; 
  }

  _tfGSM.text = (NSString*) mostLikelyPhoneNumber;

  // Releasing memory used in this particular iteration
  [NSStringphoneNumber release];
  [NSStringphoneNumberLabel release];  
 }

 // Releasing rest of memory  THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES!
 [mostLikelyPhoneNumber release];
 CFRelease(phoneNumberLabel); 
 CFRelease(phoneNumber); 
 CFRelease(multiValueReference);

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 return NO; // As soon as a person is picked, we end this address book sidetrip and return to the app
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem seems to be not understanding what `=` means.

When you assign one pointer value to another, as in this randomly chosen example:

```
mostLikelyPhoneNumber = (NSMutableString*) NSStringphoneNumber;
```

you are *not* copying the contents of the second string into the mutable first string. Rather, you are overwriting the pointer itself. So the original pointer to the `NSMutableString` you allocated earlier is *lost*, and you now have only a second reference to the `NSStringphoneNumber` value, which **you do not own**.

You do pretty much the same thing *everywhere* in your code.

When you eventually hope to clean up, you can't, because you no longer have pointers to any of your allocated objects; and when you *try*, you instead over-release a bunch of things you don't own, leading to a crash.

Normally in these situations I'd suggest going and reading the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), but frankly I think you'd better go back to basics and do some remedial C first.

Comment: That bad, huh. Well, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: On the other hand, with a few adjustments I got it to work without crashing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.